# Can OpenGL VBOs leak memory?

Tags: opengl

Suppose I call glGenBuffers (or createBuffer in WebGL), and later I lose the buffer name. E.g. it goes out of scope, is garbage collected, whatever the case may be. Making an analogy to C programming, that seems like a memory leak. Effectively, there's a block of allocated memory (on the GPU) with no pointer to it. I'm guessing the GPU can't garbage collect that memory, because it can't automatically infer that the client application is done with it.

First, is this indeed a memory leak? Second, if I call glDeleteBuffers (or deleteBuffer in WebGL) before losing my buffer name, does that free the memory and avoid a leak?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, that will cause a memory leak. You have to call [`glDeleteBuffers`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glDeleteBuffers.xhtml) for every allocated buffer. If you call it, it frees the data on the GPU and reverts the binding to 0. If you wouldn't call it, GPU would eventually run out of memory and your driver would probably crash.

Also note, that you don't need to call `glDeleteBuffers` after every call of `glBufferData`, it destroys any data that was previously bound to it. Call `glDeleteBuffers` only once, when you won't use the buffer anymore.

Comment: Also note that `glDeleteBuffers (...)` does not immediately delete a buffer. If it is being used in a multi-context setup, and the buffer is bound in a different context it will not be deleted until it is unbound there. The rule is that if after calling `glDeleteBuffers (...)` there is a reference count of 0, the data store can be freed. Under normal circumstances unbinding the buffer object takes care of this reference count, but `glDeleteBuffers (...)` only unbinds the buffer from the calling context.

Comment: Note that many, if not all OpenGL implementations will swap unused memory objects out of GPU/server memory so technically, as far as OpenGL is concerned, there is virtually unlimited memory available. The GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY indicates, that no memory for the previous request could be allocated. This can be for example, if a object creation was requested with a size that exceeds the maximum working set size of the implementation. So yes, eventually the process will run in an out of error situation, but with most implementations this happens far later than naively expected.

Comment: When would the leaked memory be recovered? When the application exits, when the system restarts...?